# Observer Pattern with Generics

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to learn the Observer pattern after reading the MSDN docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/observer-design-pattern. When using with inheritance, it errors and does not allow me to create common observers. Below is my code:

```
interface Book { }

class ComicBook : Book { }
class ComicBookObserver : IObserver<ComicBook>
{
    public void OnCompleted() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public void OnError(Exception error) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public void OnNext(ComicBook value) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}

class Publisher : IObservable<Book>
{
    private List<IObserver<ComicBook>> ComicBookObservers = new List<IObserver<ComicBook>>();
    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<Book> observer) 
    {
        if (observer is IObserver<ComicBook>)
            ComicBookObservers.Add(observer);
        return null;
    }
}

class Main
{
    public static void main(string[] args)
    {
        Publisher p = new Publisher();
        p.Subscribe(new ComicBookObserver());
    }
}
```

I receive the error on `p.Subscribe(new ComicBookObserver());`:

```
Cannot convert from 'ComicBookObserver' to 'System.IObserver<Book>'
```

Why is the case since A ComicBook is also a Book. Is this not allowed? Would I have to create `Subcribe` methods for all different types of books?

Comment: You can read about covariance and contravariance https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/

Comment: This is the case here - IObserver declared as IObserver<[NullableAttribute(2)] in T>.

Comment: Your code will compile if you define `ComicBookObserver : IObserver<Book>` and `Publisher : IObservable<ComicBook>`.

Comment: The reason is simple - you have another type which implements IObservable<Book>. It means that in case of another event it should call OnNext(Book value) method of an observer IOberver<Book>, but you try to pass there IObserver<ComicBook>. I.e. your observer won't work for any Book, but for ComicBook only, and it breaks the contract.

Comment: And the opposite would work - when you have IObserver<Book> you can put there ComicBook and it is correct. Because any ComicBook is Book, but not every Book is ComicBook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, `ComicBookObserver` implements `IObserver<ComicBook>`, therefore it wants to see `ComicBook`.

`Publisher` implements `IObservable<Book>`, therefore it outputs `Book`.

The `Book` interface does not satisfy the more derived `ComicBook` type required by the `ComicBookObserver`.

If you need to observe specific types then yes you will need to subscribe multiple times with subscribers specific to those types.

You could use the Rx `OfType<ComicBook>()` [method](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/08_Transformation.html#CastAndOfType) to create a new observable from your `IObservable<Book>`.

E.g:

```
Publisher p = new Publisher();
p.OfType<ComicBook>().Subscribe(new ComicBookObserver());
```

This has the advantage that only items of type `ComicBook` will be observed and you won't need to perform any additional type checks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can continue with you pattern, but add one wrinkle.  I would make the ComicBook observer implement `IObserver<Book>` and then in your implementation you need to process `ComicBook` items and discard the rest.  arguably you'll be subscribing other  Observers for other types of books.  they would follow this pattern as well.

```
interface Book { }

class ComicBook : Book { }
class OtherBook : Book { }
class ComicBookObserver : IObserver<Book>
{
    public void OnCompleted() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public void OnError(Exception error) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public void OnNext(Book value) 
    {   
        if (value is ComicBook)
        {
            // logic for Comic Book values
        }
    }
}

class OthereBookObserver : IObserver<Book>
{
    public void OnCompleted() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public void OnError(Exception error) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public void OnNext(Book value) 
    {   
        if (value is OtherBook)
        {
            // logic for other book values
        }
    }
}

class Publisher : IObservable<Book>
{
    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<Book> observer) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}

class Main
{
    public static void main(string[] args)
    {
        Publisher p = new Publisher();
        p.Subscribe(new ComicBookObserver());
        p.Subscribe(new OtherBookObserver());
    }
}
```